# Inner Join in ON Clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a MySQL query that is trying to get all the Pages that contain Data like 'word%'.  I have a many-to-many table called Pages2Data.  It seems that to do this, I need to have an inner join connecting the Pages to the Pages2Data table, and then another inner join connecting Pages2Data to Data.

The following did not work, because the nested SELECT clause can return more than one row.  I'm not sure how to fix it though:

```
SELECT * FROM `Pages` 
   INNER JOIN `Pages2Data` ON 
      (`Pages2Data`.`DataID`=(SELECT `DataID` FROM `Data` WHERE `DataWord` LIKE 'word%'))
      AND `Pages`.`PageID`=`Pages2Data`.`PageID`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `Pages`     
INNER JOIN `Pages2Data`
   ON `Pages`.`PageID`=`Pages2Data`.`PageID`
INNER JOIN `Data` ON `Data`.`DataID`= `Pages2Data`.`DataID`
WHERE `DataWord` LIKE 'word%';
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it this way as opposed to JellyBelly's method above without inner joins?

Comment: Implicit joins are bad for maintenance (wait until you need to add a left jon to another table and see what a I mean) and are far more likely to have errors creep in such as accidental cross joins. They were replaced almost 20 years ago with a better syntax, There is no circumstance (except supporting an old database which did not have the syntax yet) I think of where I would support them being used in new code. The separation of the where clasue from the join also makes it clearer in the future what was intended.

Comment: Interesting... I appreciate the explanation!  One last question: In your query, which clause is called first?  The where clause or the inner joins?

Comment: In mysql I don't know, in SQl Server they would have the same execution plan and the same performance.

Comment: In theory, the JOINs are done first (based on the ON conditions) and then the WHERE conditions are applied. In practise and what actual databases do is "compile" the query and come up with a sometimes complex optimization plan, depending on the table sizes, the existing indexes that can be used, etc. The result is guaranteed to be the same though (except possibly for the order of rows display).

Answer (score 1):

First the problems with your query:

1. the join condition should be next to the ON clause
2. there is no WHERE clause in the outer most query

Fixed query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Pages` 
INNER JOIN `Pages2Data` ON `Pages`.`PageID`=`Pages2Data`.`PageID`
WHERE `Pages2Data`.`DataID`= (SELECT `DataID` FROM `Data` WHERE `DataWord` LIKE 'word%');
```

Alternative query:

```
SELECT `PG`.*
FROM `Pages` `PG`
INNER JOIN `Pages2Data` `PD` ON `PD`.`PageID` = `PG`.`PageID`
INNER JOIN `Data` `DA` ON `PD`.`DataID` = `DA`.`DataID`
WHERE `DA`.`DataWord` LIKE 'word%';
```

Comment: The first query of yours should have: `WHERE Pages2Data.DataID IN (SELECT ...`

Comment: Yeah, sure it should. I just pasted the original query and fixed the issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM `Pages` p, `Pages2Data` p2d, `Data` d
WHERE p.`PageID` = p2d.`PageID`
AND p2d.`DataID` = d.`DataID`
AND `DataWord` LIKE 'word%'
```

Comment: Although don't know that the `SELECT *` will return the columns wanted in this instance

Comment: Wow, I also feel dumb for not spotting that this could have been much simpler.  Thanks for seeing it, JellyBelly.  I wonder if this is the optimal order though?  Perhaps the LIKE statement should come first in the WHERE clause, because that needs to be run anyway, and it would narrow down how much work needs to be done for the ID matching.  Thoughts?

Comment: I think that is indifferent! :D

Comment: Implicit syntax was replaced in 1992 with a better syntax that is clearer, easier to maintain and less likely to create problems with accidental cross joins. There is no reason to use implict joins in new code and the use of it should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can check 'Like' in where clause.

```
SELECT * FROM 
           `Pages` 
INNER JOIN 
           `Pages2Data` ON  (`Pages`.`PageID`=`Pages2Data`.`PageID`)
WHERE
            `DataWord` LIKE 'word%'
```

Comment: DataWord is in a third table called Data that isn't in your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Pages
   INNER JOIN Pages2Data
      ON Pages.PageID = Pages2Data.PageID
   INNER JOIN Data
      ON Pages2Data.DataID = Data.DataID
WHERE DataWord LIKE 'word%'
```